# Equal and hashcode collision in c#

Tags: c#, equals, hashcode

i wrote the following code in c#:

```
public class Person
{
    private string idNumber;
    private string personName;
    public Person(string name, string id)
    {
        this.personName= name;
        this.idNumber= id;
    }
    public override bool Equals(Objectobj)
    {
        Person personObj= obj as Person;
        if(personObj== null) 
            return false;
        else 
            return idNumber.Equals(personObj.idNumber);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    { 
        return this.idNumber.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Person p1 = new Person("John", "63412895");
    Person p2 = new Person("Jack", "63412895");
    Console.WriteLine(p1.Equals(p2));
    Console.WriteLine(Object.Equals(p1, p2));
}
```

i don't understand why the second `Console.WriteLine()` returns true???
the first returns true since i override equal method.
but the second one related to equal in object class.
please explain.

Comment: If your code is exactly like that I have doubts it compiles

Comment: I hope this is a copy paste issue `public override bool Equals(Objectobj)`

Comment: I noticed it's a sample from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :)
Note, here is overriden Equals method so those operations give the same result:
p1.Equals(p2)
p2.Equals(p1)
Object.Equals(p1, p2)
Object.Equals(p2, p1)
Additionally, the hash codes are created only from idNumbers which are the same.

Answer (score 5):

The static `object.Equals` method is defined as

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
{
    if (objA==objB) {
        return true;
    }
    if (objA==null || objB==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

So internally it uses the overriden `Equals` after `null` checks.

To compare references, use `object.ReferenceEquals` or cast to `object` and use `==` operator.

```
object.ReferenceEquals(p1, p2)
(object)p1 == (object)p2
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote from MSDN documentation on `Object.Equals(Object, Object)`

> If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and
>   neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result.
>   This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method,
>   this override is called.

I believe that's exactly what happens in your scenario. Since you have overridden the `Equals` method, it is being called internally by the `Object`'s static method.

Answer (score 1):

The second line of code internally checks if p1 is null and calls the first line.

So you can't expect to have diferent results calling almost the same method.

```
p1.Equals(p2);
Object.Equals(p1, p2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is related to the fact that you also override GetHashcode which is used by Object.Equals. That's my guess.

Answer (score -1):

You overrode GetHashCode.  That is what the object equality is using.   The classic example is in .Net the two objects objStringA ="MyVal"  and ObjStringB = 'MyVal"   will return equal because the string overrides the get hash code.

It is like you overrode it twice.  I am not sure you needed the Equals operator to be overridden in your case.